# Probability of hitting a certain sum with dice

Tags: probability, dice

Using $5$ $6$-faced dice, what's the probability of hitting a cumulative sum $S$, on a particular roll (each roll incorporates all $5$ dice), if $15 \leq S\leq 20$?

I reckon this particular situation could be considered equivalent to a similar set of circumstances in which we'd roll the same die $5$ consecutive times and take the total sum.

I thought the way to a possible solution would be to consider the following generating function :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{6^{5}}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^5$$

Next up, I believe I should compute the sum of polynomial coefficients going from degree $15$ up to $20$, but I'm not sure this is the way, so please share your thoughts.

But if I'm right, how can I calculate this tedious sum?

Comment: Use a CAS or write a program in your favorite language.

Comment: Um, well does this imply the thinking is correct ?

Comment: You should be able to figure out whether your proposed procedure computes the correct probability on your own. As to the question of actually implementing this procedure, this is just a question of programming.

Comment: So anyone here, no matter their level and preparation should not be asking any questions because they should be able to figure it out any way ? Remarkable logic, truly.

Comment: Exactly. You ask a question if you don't know what to do, or if you get stuck. You don't ask a question to get psychological support, though I'm sure you will still get an answer.

Comment: I'm not asking for psychological support, I'm ask for verification (verification (ˌvɛrɪfɪˈkeɪʃən)
n
1. establishment of the correctness of a theory, fact, etc) just to clear your mind, since you're obviously quite confused . Since you're clearly unable to provide any insight, I kindly ask you to leave this post and go on your way.

Comment: [Follow this link](http://anydice.com/program/1c7), then click "At Least". :)

Comment: [Here is an alternative approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2089001/139123) using a relatively simple spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your actual question, how to calculate the tedious sum, you can use a computer algebra software such as [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[Coefficient[%28x%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E6%29%5E5%2F6%5E5%2Cx%5ES]%2CS%3D15..20]) to get the exact solution, $361/648$.

Another option is to use dynamic programming directly. Let $P(n,S)$ be the probability that the sum of $n$ cubes equals $S$. Then $P(0,0) = 1$, $P(0,S) = 0$ for $S \neq 0$, and for $n \geq 1$,
$$ P(n,S) = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{s=1}^6 P(n-1,S-s). $$
You can implement this recurrence using dynamic programming efficiently.