# Generalizing Probabilities for Summed Dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to build a formula that accurately describes the probabilities of each of the sums that can be produced from rollings dice together and adding up their results.

For example, if I roll 2d6, or two d6 dice with their values added up, the probabilities of each possible result can be described by this table:

\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
Roll & Probability \\ \hline
2    & 1/36        \\ \hline
3    & 2/36        \\ \hline
4    & 3/36        \\ \hline
5    & 4/36        \\ \hline
6    & 5/36        \\ \hline
7    & 6/36        \\ \hline
8    & 5/36        \\ \hline
9    & 4/36        \\ \hline
10   & 3/36        \\ \hline
11   & 2/36        \\ \hline
12   & 1/36        \\ \hline
\end{array}

Similarly, were I to roll 3d6, or three d6 dice with their values added up, these probabilities can be represented like this:

\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
Roll & Probability \\ \hline
3    & 1/216       \\ \hline
4    & 3/216       \\ \hline
5    & 6/216       \\ \hline
6    & 10/216      \\ \hline
7    & 15/216      \\ \hline
8    & 21/216      \\ \hline
9    & 25/216      \\ \hline
10   & 27/216      \\ \hline
11   & 27/216      \\ \hline
12   & 25/216      \\ \hline
13   & 21/216      \\ \hline
14   & 15/216      \\ \hline
15   & 10/216      \\ \hline
16   & 6/216       \\ \hline
17   & 3/216       \\ \hline
18   & 1/216       \\ \hline
\end{array}

The problem is that I arrived at these values manually, by building tables of possible rolls and accumulating the number of rolls that result in a given sum. This quickly becomes infeasible for larger numbers of rolls. So I'd like to know how to generalize this formula for arbitrary (but specific and predetermined) numbers of dice.

I'd also like to know this formula for non-cubic dice (rolling several regular d8 dice, for example), and, if possible, Heterogeneous Dice (like a d8 rolled with a d6, for example).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357442/distribution-of-sum-of-discrete-uniform-random-variables

Comment: For a large number of **equal die** you can apply the central limit theorem. For different situations I don´t see a general approach.

Comment: @callculus I'm not sure how the CLT is useful here, given that I'm trying to build a table of probabilities, not merely approximate them.

Comment: But you want a general formula, right? This formula does not exist. If you want a table for a specific situation you have to look for a specific formula. Maybe it exists or not.

Comment: If you don't care about using technology to help you, rolling an amount of $k$ dice each of which $n$-sided, you will get a total sum of $r$ with probability equal to the coefficient of $x^r$ in the expansion of $\left(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots+x^n\right)^k/n^k$.

Comment: Building these tables with pencil and paper alone is a chore, but a computer can easily build tables for large numbers of dice. Even a software spreadsheet can do it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2089001/139123

Comment: There is a formula for the individual probabilities, but since you want the entire PMF, you’re better off using one of the methods described [here](https://m.wikihow.com/Calculate-Multiple-Dice-Probabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Generating functions will give you the probabilities.  For example for a $6$-sided die, the coefficients in the expansion of $$\frac{x(1-x^6)}{6(1-x)} = \frac16 x^1 +\frac16 x^2 +\frac16 x^3 +\frac16 x^4 +\frac16 x^5 +\frac16 x^6$$ give the probabilities, and similarly for other dice for dice with other numbers of sides you get $\frac{x(1-x^s)}{s(1-x)}$

You can then find the probabilities of sums from throwing several independent dice by multiplying their generating functions, so in your example of the sum of three $6$-sided die the generating function is  $$\left(\frac{x(1-x^6)}{6(1-x)}\right)^3$$ which you can then expand to find the coefficients